# jQuery datatables export input text option and not export specific column at same time

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've been struggling with this code. I need to avoid specific columns from being exported. I have done that but I don't know how to export the text inside any input element.

Here is the code:

```
$("#campaignMaterialsTable table").DataTable({
                            dom: 'Bfrtip',
                            buttons: [
                                {
                                    extend: 'excel',
                                    className: 'export-button',
                                    text: 'Export as Excel',
                                    columns: ':not(.notexport)',
                                    //exportOptions: {
                                    //    format: {
                                    //        body: function (data, row, column, node) {
                                    //            //
                                    //            //check if type is input using jquery
                                    //            return $(data).is("input") ?
                                    //                $(data).val() :
                                    //                data;
                                    //        },
                                    //        columns: ':not(.notexport)'
                                    //    }
                                    //},
                                    title: 'Campaign Materials'
                                }]
                        });
```

I don't know here to put the code at the right place.. while initializing..

I referred to this links, but still not getting what I want:

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50724/export-values-typed-in-input-box-excelhtml5

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42205/export-data-with-text-box-in-td-of-data-table#latest

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50724/export-values-typed-in-input-box-excelhtml5

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i didn't know that. but i was in a really urgent situation. thats why.. i thought i would get some help.. but i ran out of time..and found an alternate solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have a DataTable containing one or more input fields, something like this:

[image]

The user can type values into the input fields.

You want to export data to Excel, so that the result looks like this:

[image]

Here we can see the user-provided data as well as the standard table data.

To achieve this, I used the following table data:

```
<table id="example" class="display nowrap dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Adélaïde Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="office" name="office"></td>
            <td>432434</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td>Maager</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="office" name="office"></td>
            <td>6123</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John Smith 2</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="office" name="office"></td>
            <td>6123</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I used the following DataTable initialization code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',

      buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'excel',
          exportOptions: {
            format: {
              body: function ( inner, rowidx, colidx, node ) {
                if ($(node).children("input").length > 0) {
                  return $(node).children("input").first().val();
                } else {
                  return inner;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]

    });

  });
</script>
```

The `body` function assumes that, for input fields, there is only an `input` field in the cell (i.e. the input field is not contained in a `form` or any other element).

It uses the node parameter to check for input data, to avoid data formatting issues that could occur (e.g. with dates). I recommend doing that rather than using `$(data).is("input")`.

If there is no input field found in the cell, then the cell contents (`inner`) are returned.

If the structure of your table does not match these assumptions, then you may need to adjust the above code, of course.

### Edit

Regarding the follow-up question about choosing  which columns to export, there are various ways.

You can hard-code the column indexes you want to export (where index 0 means the first column). For example:

```
exportOptions: {
  columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 ],
    format: {
      body: function ( inner, rowidx, colidx, node ) {
        if ($(node).children("input").length > 0) {
          return $(node).children("input").first().val();
        } else {
          return inner;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This exports all columns apart from the Start Date column (index 4).

Or you can use the approach in your question, based on a class, I believe. I have not actually tried that one.

Take note of where the `columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 ]` directive is placed - it is inside the `exportOptions` section.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i need to know how to merge the code for ignoring specific columns from being exported with the code you have provided. By the way i used another technique to solve my problem. i was in damn urgent in the morning. my boss was after me. cuz we had to deliver the project around 12: pm IST and i posted this question before < 1hour for 12:00 pm.

Comment: your code helps to export the data of any input element. how to merge the code for ignoring specific columns with your code..i hope you understand.

Comment: very tired at the end of the day. i'll try myself again with the code you have provided tomorrow.

Comment: I added an example for you.

Comment: the update you provided is working the either way. thanks

Comment: @halfer - Edit noted; guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
exportOptions:{
       columns: ':visible'
 }
```

in below buttons

```
buttons: [
   {
       extend: 'pdf',
       footer: true,
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible'
        }


   },
```

it will export only visible columns

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i also need to merge the code for exporting the text inside the input element. can you help me with that..i have included that code in the question - its commented

Comment: This code -> return $(data).is("input") ?$(data).val() :data;

Comment: merge the above code with Columns: ":not(not-export)" options