# Jquery Datatable Export to excel Not Working with Html Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am working in a Laravel project where I use jquery datatable to display lists of data. I also added Excel download button in datatable by using the options provided by the datatable.

In the listing, there is a  box which is used to change the status (placed, processing, delivered, cancelled) of a listing.

The problem is that, whenever I am trying to export the listing as excel sheet, all column values are displaying well in the downloaded excel, but the status field () box displaying the first  "placed" value for each listing even if they are value with "processing" or "cancelled".

What is the reason behind this ? Am I missing some option in datatable ? Here is my code :

**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                
                "bPaginate": false,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                extend:    'csvHtml5',
                text:      '<img src="{{asset('admin_assets/images/CSV-logo.jpg')}}">',
                titleAttr: 'CSV'
            },
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<img src="{{asset('admin_assets/images/excel.jpg')}}">',
                titleAttr: 'Excel'
            },
                ],
            });
        } );
```

**

I got stuck here. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_there is a box which is used to change the status_" - You haven't shown us any of that code, so this is a guess: You can use `exportOptions` with `format.body` to access the nodes of each relevant field, See [jQuery datatables export input text option...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62145571/12567365) for a full example. When a user manually types data into an input field in a DataTable, that data only exists in the DOM (the HTML `<td>` node) - it does not exist in the underlying DataTable. The DataTable only contains the data which was provided when the DataTable was first created.

Comment: If the linked answer does not help you to solve your problem, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Hello @andrewJames Thank you for replying. In my listing table, there is a field "status" which uses a select box to change the status of a particular listing. The problem is that when I try to export an excel, it exports only first <option> in the select box even if the second <option> is selected. This is the issue. If you want to know more, let me know, I will discuss to you. Thanks...

Comment: Look at the answer in the link I already provided.