# Update Export-Data on DataTable

Tags: datatables

I have a DataTable that is editable via Input Fields and Ajax. After each successful Ajax-request I update the `data-searchable` and `data-orderable` as well as the data displayed in the cell and then invalidate the cells so that the search and ordering of the dataTable uses the new data. I use the following code for that:

```
$(target).closest('td').attr('data-search', $(target).val())
$(target).closest('td').attr('data-order', $(target).val())
$(target).siblings('span').text($(target).val())
tables.base.cell($(target).closest('td')).invalidate();
```

However the dataTables generated PDF export still seems to use the initial data and doesn't update. Is there any way to update the data used for the export?

Comment: I have not tried your specific scenario, but you can access the `<td>` node of a DataTables table cell using `format.body` (see details on [this page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData())). An example of doing this is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62153153/12567365).