# Is there a way to change Responsive DataTables column title based on breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, datatables, responsive

I'm using DataTables with Resposive module. I would like to display different column titles with different breakpoints. So for example for on large screens (breakpoint: desktop) title of one column should be "Position", while on smaller screens (breakpoint: not-desktop or mobile/tablet) should be "Pos."

One solution I could think of is to use 2 different columns with same content but different column title. One column I can make visible on dekstop, other column on not-desktop. This is a possible solution for the problem but it comes with various other issues, for example we have an Excel export functionality on our tables and the duplicated columns should be managed also there.

So maybe there's some other easy solution which does not need to have duplicated columns.

Comment: Regarding your point about exporting to Excel: If you do end up using duplicated columns, you can avoid exporting them with the `exportOptions: columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 5 ] ... }` approach - and other [column selectors](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector), including CSS class names. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62153153/12567365).

Comment: Otherwise, you can probably make use of [DataTables Responsive events](https://datatables.net/reference/event/#responsive) to handle the column heading changes automatically (I have not looked into this).